# TCP/IP client server Communication over different network C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, xamarin

I try to Make my client and my Server communicate by sending a small request to get the Time, but it's working only if they're in the same network . 
My Client is a Xamarin Application 
and My server is a Console Application .

For Now , I Could make them communicate on the same network , but as for my project they have to communicate by disant . I tried to read some .NET.Sockets Documentation , but I can't find the right answer for my problem .

Code for Client

```cs
protected void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        { int attempts = 0;


           while (!clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                attempts++;
                gettext.Text = "Connection attempts:" + attempts.ToString();
                clientSocket.Connect("192.168.0.107", 100);
            }
            gettext.Text = "Connected";
            SendLoop();
        }



private  void SendLoop()
        {

                gettext.Text = "get time";
                string req = gettext.Text;
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
                clientSocket.Send(buffer);
                byte[] BuffRec = new byte[1024];
                int rec = clientSocket.Receive(BuffRec);
                byte[] data = new byte[rec];
                Array.Copy(BuffRec, data, rec);
                gettext.Text = "Received:" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

        }
```

Code for Server

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Server
{
    class Server
    {
        private static readonly Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static readonly List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
        private const int PORT = 100;
        private static readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Title = "DENM";
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine(); // When we press enter close everything
            CloseAllSockets();
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
            serverSocket.Listen(0);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete");

            //Using the AddressFamily, SocketType, and ProtocolType properties.
            Console.WriteLine("I just set the following properties of socket: " + "\nAddress Family = " + serverSocket.AddressFamily.ToString() + "\nSocketType = " + serverSocket.SocketType.ToString() + "\nProtocolType = " + serverSocket.ProtocolType.ToString());            Console.WriteLine("I am connected to " + IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint)serverSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()) + "on port number " + ((IPEndPoint)serverSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString());

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close all connected client (we do not need to shutdown the server socket as its connections
        /// are already closed with the clients).
        /// </summary>
        private static void CloseAllSockets()
        {
            foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }

            serverSocket.Close();
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket;

            try
            {
                socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) // I cannot seem to avoid this (on exit when properly closing sockets)
            {
                return;
            }

            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected, waiting for request...");
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received;

            try
            {
                received = current.EndReceive(AR);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
                // Don't shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway.
                current.Close();
                clientSockets.Remove(current);
                return;
            }

            byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);

            if (text.ToLower() == "get time") // Client requested time
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Text is a get time request");
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                current.Send(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Time sent to client");
            }
            else if (text.ToLower() == "exit") // Client wants to exit gracefully
            {
                // Always Shutdown before closing
                current.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                current.Close();
                clientSockets.Remove(current);
                Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Text is an invalid request");
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Invalid request");
                current.Send(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Warning Sent");
            }

            current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to make my mobile app communicate with the server even if they're on a different network

Comment: your server needs to have a public IP address.  192.168.*.* is a local address that will only be reachable by other devices on the same network.

Comment: First from cmd.exe try >Ping IP  (or computer name).  You may need to use computer name instead of IP (both for ping and in your application).  If Ping is not working then you do not have a route.  The Ethernet card has a IP address and a Mask and the Mask may not be correct on you computer or the Gateway or a router.

Comment: Plus the remote network's firewall needs to allow incoming connections to port 100 (many don't.)

Comment: @Jason I trend to change it to my public IP address , which is in this format : 193.50.*.* but it's not working

Comment: @Duston , My Firewall is disabled

Comment: Your firewall is disabled, what about the one on the far end?

Comment: You may need to forward the port from your public IP (on your router) to your internal IP of the computer running the server.